# Why is my iOS App taking so much memory and CPU?

Tags: ios, memory, reference, swift2

I have this simple app that has a simple menu screen. But for some reason the memory is over 130 mb and CPU always rises above 80 percent. Is this normal? or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the profiling image:

[image]

Here is the menu scene:

[image]

Here is the debug navigator:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

  var gameScene: SKScene!
  var skView: SKView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.changeScene(_:)), name: "ChangedScene", object: nil)
    skView = self.view as! SKView
    gameScene = IntroScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    gameScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(gameScene)
  }

  func changeScene(notification: NSNotification) {

    let message = notification.userInfo!["sceneName"] as! String

    let transition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(.Left, duration: 1.0)
    if message == "SelectScene" {
      gameScene = SelectScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
      skView.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
    }

    if message == "MatchingGameScene" {
      gameScene = MatchingGameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
      skView.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
    }

    if message == "SoundGameScene" {
      gameScene = SoundGameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
      skView.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
    }
  }

  override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
      return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
      return .All
    }
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
  }

  override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

As you can see the memory usage is 130mb and CPU is over 80 percent. Is this normal? I was expecting it to be much smaller than 130mb and 80 percent because the entire app file including images is just a bit over 2.5 mb. Why is this happening?

Comment: You should drill down  - what is taking the memory?  Use the other instruments to find out where the CPU is being consumed.

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or on Simulator? Don't take Simulator's results into account. It uses software renderer. Always test on real device if you are interested into real performance of your app.

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually checking on a real device?. The Xcode simulator uses about 3 times as much ram as real device and CPU usage is always very high.

Running on a real device you will see that your  CPU usage will go down a lot and memory will go down to about 40-50Mb. That is normal for a spriteKit game and you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12001679)

Comment: Why?. This is a valid answer. The xCode simulator always uses about 3 time as much ram as a real device. Furthermore CPU usage is always very high, around 80%. Therefore I am pointing out that to get a real idea you need to test on a real device before coming to the conclusion that you have a memory problem or wonder why its so high. His numbers are actually normal for a Spritekit game.

Comment: He's saying that it's not an answer to OP's question, but rather to post it as a comment.

Comment: He is asking if it's normal and I am telling him it is and that the simulator is not a good indicator. What is supposed to be the answer? There is no point telling the op about instruments and ask him to check for leaks etc when he doesn't even have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually hard to answer and what are you doing is a good approach, I mean using instrument tool to analyze. This is just my 2 cents that the root cause probably is about animations. 
If you perform animations but don't stop them properly, they are still running and consuming your memory. I experienced this when customizing a table view cell consists an animation. I did not stop the animation before the cell deallocated, so it was still there and consuming memory.